# Can I turn exe file into .app file for mac

Tags: python, c++, exe, .app

I have a c++ file and a python file.

I can turn both of these to `.exe` files. But I can't turn them into `.app` files.

I am using the `pyinstaller` module for python files.

How can I turn the files into `.app` files?

Comment: ".app files" are actually folders, called "bundles". (You can right-click one in the Finder and choose "View contents" or view its contents in the terminal.) The structure of the folder is described in Apple's documentation.

Comment: I know this but unfortunately it doesn't work for me :) @molbdnilo

Answer (score 1):

As per PyInstaller's documentation, you can use it also to build a mac application. However, you would have to build it from Mac OS.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#building-mac-os-x-app-bundles

Comment: I will check, I'll edit this comment if it works. @ApplePie